What information we can obtain from total transverse energy and transverse momentum plots on particle physics
I am working on particle physics simulations and making some plots for which the purpose are not yet clear to me, as I am a novice in this field of study. To make my doubts clear, let's consider an event on the LHC:
                                 p + p --> C + D --> C-jets + D-jets.

I would like to know:

what information one can obtain from the histograms of the total transverse energy (H_T) of this event?

what information one can obtain from a plot of the transverse momentum ( P_T) of C or D jets, for this event?

If we have another event, which has the same final state jets (C and D jets) as the one I mentioned above, like
                              p + p --> A + B --> C-jets + D-jets



Which is not the same event, but has the same final state as the first event.
Should I have the same distribution and average values of H_T and P_T for both events?
Thanks for the help.
